# string u' encoding problem

Tags: arcpy

the goal of my program is to retrieve data from a field one after another at the end to compare with other values of another table
when I execute the code that allows me to point to the values of the first field I get a string that starts with u '
What should I do to remove the u'

DataSource= Shapefile

```
cursor=arcpy.da.SearchCursor("Feuil1$","LIAISON_NOM")
for row in cursor:
print(str(row))
```

i get this

```
>>>>(u'ROAD 1',)
    (u'ROAD 2',)
```

Comment: I think you will find that the u makes no difference to what you are trying to do. If you find it does then can you elaborate about any problem beyond aesthetics that it causes.

Comment: Please edit th question to specify the data aource type (e.g., file geodatabase, shapefile,...), and the field type. You haven't demonstrated a *problem* with encoding, just a *fact of* encoding.

Comment: the problem is when I compare the value " ROAD 1"  another value with the == operator even if there is a conection the program does not recognize it

Comment: Casting between `unicode` and `str` is a Python issue (more specifically, Python 2.7, since Python 3.x uses `unicode` as `str`).  Have you tried casting with `str()` or prefixing your comparison constant with `u`?

Answer (score 1):

The `u''` just indicates that the string is encoded as unicode rather than ASCII. If you print *just* the string with `print(row[0])` (instead of the whole row tuple) you should see the values as you'd expect, e.g. `ROAD 1`.

Comment: even with the row [0] I still have the "u" which appears