# Way processing is too slow in osm2pgsql?

Tags: performance, osm2pgsql

I'm importing the planet data file. After see the `Node` processing taking about a hour at `2800.0 k/s` to finish I think all job will be fast but now `Way` is still working after 28 hours at `0.5 k/s` and done just `31.583k` of `402.887k` ! ([OSM stats](http://www.openstreetmap.org/stats/data_stats.html)).

The `top` command shows it taking 15% of RAM and 5% of CPU.

My import command was

`$osm2pgsql --number-processes 6 --flat-nodes ./osm_flat_nodes.db --disable-parallel-indexing --latlong --verbose --create --hstore --slim --cache 4000 --database osm --username postgres --host 127.0.0.1 --style ./default.style ./planet-latest.osm.pbf`

My machine:
`CentOS / 32GB RAM / 600GB HDD / 8 Cores`

Is this normal?

[image]

Comment: After installing `atop` I can see a high disk I/O usage.

Comment: https://github.com/openstreetmap/osm2pgsql/issues/534 AND https://github.com/openstreetmap/osm2pgsql/issues/517#issuecomment-164551795

Comment: Is NOT duplicate of http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/190701/string-u-encoding-problem (`string u' encoding problem`). Please remove the flag for this question to avoid other users to go there.